# Updating new revision for google drive native documents

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a document in google drive. I want to upload a new revision for the same document using google drive android sdk. I tried the code like,

```
try{
                                                                            // First retrieve the file from the API.
  File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("sdcard0/temp/test.doc");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.google-apps.document", fileContent);

File updatedFile = service.files().update(getID(), file, mediaContent).execute();                                   
} catch (IOException e1) {
       Log.d("","An error occurred: " + e1); //No i18n
} catch (Exception e){
       Log.d("","EXCEPTION IN SAVING"+e); //No i18n
}
```

But the content looks like corrupted in docs.google.com like[image]

Please guide me if am doing anything wrong.

Note: the same code works well for uploaded document.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use those revisions for native formats like google docs. Those have their own apis to modify them. For example spreadsheets has the spreadsheet feed api.

Comment: May i know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new revision for a Google Docs/Spreadsheet format using the convert parameter in the [update request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update).

Following your code modified to enable conversion while uploading (not tested but confident it's correct)

```
try{
    // First retrieve the file from the API.
    File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("sdcard0/temp/test.doc");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/msword", fileContent); //Changed the mime type to original

    File updatedFile = service.files().update(getID(), file, mediaContent)
                        .setConvert(true) //Convert the file while uploading
                        .execute();                                   
} catch (IOException e1) {
       Log.d("","An error occurred: " + e1); //No i18n
} catch (Exception e){
       Log.d("","EXCEPTION IN SAVING"+e); //No i18n
}
```

Comment: I think It's android code, but can you confirm? I'll try writing a test app. I use a similar code in my Android App but with txt files as source and the file is converted correctly (with the insert, maybe there is a bug on convert for the update)